Denesting Method for $\sqrt[3]{-10+9\sqrt{-3}}$ (Without Solving Another Cubic Equation)?
To solve the cubic equation $$x^3-2x^2-x+2=0$$such an answer is obtained: $$\sqrt[3]{-10+9\sqrt{-3}}$$ which can not be easily denested manually.
For denesting that radical, I had to solve another cubic equation. Sometimes, this second cubic equation would be more complex than the main equation. Is there any way for denesting a radical, which does not generate a new cubic equation? (hint: the denested form is $\sqrt[3]{-10+9\sqrt{-3}}=2+\sqrt{-3}$)

Well $x=2$ is a solution to the original cubic, so you're essentially solving a quadratic.

thank you, but how you can find that?

Rational root thereom.  If on rational roots exist (which they might not) it must be $\pm 1,\pm 2$ as $x=2$ yield $x^2 = 2x^2$ and $x=2$ the sum is $0$.

I found a really simple method for solving this type of cube radical. First, we can write the radical and its conjugate as:
$$\sqrt[3]{-10+9\sqrt{-3}}=a+b\sqrt{-3}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{-10-9\sqrt{-3}}=a-b\sqrt{-3}$$
By multiplying these two expressions we have:
$$\sqrt[3]{(-10)^2-(9\sqrt{-3})^2}=a^2-(b\sqrt{-3})^2$$
$$\sqrt[3]{100-81(-3)}=a^2-b^2(-3)$$
$$a^2+3b^2=\sqrt[3]{343}=7$$
Now we can guess the values of $a^2$ and $3b^2$, then check them out. For example, we guess these values:
$$a^2=4 , 3b^2=3\Rightarrow a=±2 , b=±1$$
To check the guessed values, we should use one of the above conjugate expressions and take both sides to the third power (there's no difference in choosing which)
$$\sqrt[3]{-10+9\sqrt{-3}}=a+b\sqrt{-3}\Rightarrow -10+9\sqrt{-3}=(a+b\sqrt{-3})^3$$
$$a^3+3a^2b\sqrt{-3}+3ab^2(-3)+b^3(-3)\sqrt{-3}=-10+9\sqrt{-3}$$
$$
\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
a^3-9ab^2=-10&(1) \\
3a^2b-3b^3=9&(2)
\end{cases}
$$
Now let's put $a$ and $b$ in the above expressions to see if they satisfy them or not
$$a=+2,b=±1\Rightarrow a^3-9ab^2=2^3-9(2)(±1)^2=8-18=-10$$
So $a=+2$ is a correct guess. Now let's find the value of $b$ by putting $a$ and $b$ in the second expression
$$a=+2,b=+1\Rightarrow 3a^2b-3b^3=3(2)^2(1)-3(1)^3=12-3=9$$
So $a=2$ and $b=1$ are the correct guesses. and we can write the cube radicals as
$$\sqrt[3]{-10+9\sqrt{-3}}=2+\sqrt{-3}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{-10-9\sqrt{-3}}=2-\sqrt{-3}$$

$$\sqrt[3]{+9\sqrt{-3}-10}=\sqrt[3]{9i\sqrt{3}-10}$$
Using the hint you were given it is only natural to conclude that the original expression is $\sqrt[3]{(2+\sqrt{-3})^3}$.
We know $(a+b)^3=a^3+3ab^2+3a^2b+b^3$ in this case this becomes $(2+i\sqrt{3})^3=a^3+3ab^2+3a^2b+b^3$.
The value of $a$ is the easiest to find since we already have the $2$ in the hinted expression. Then you can guess and check and it would not take long to see that $a=2,b=i\sqrt{3}$ satisfy the equality.
$$\sqrt[3]{(i\sqrt{3}+2)^3}=i\sqrt{3}+2=2+\sqrt{-3}$$

But how did you come up with this expansion of $9i\sqrt{3}$?

$\sqrt{-3}=\sqrt{-1}\times \sqrt{3}=i\sqrt{3}$

thank you, but how can we write the expression as what you said?

$8-18=-10$ and $12i\sqrt{3}-3i\sqrt{3}=9i\sqrt{3}$

yeah, I know that bro (xD). I mean, is there any algorithm for that? not just by guessing the values.

Using the hint you were given it is only logical that inside that cube root is $(i\sqrt{3}+2)^3$ then you just play around with $(a+b)^3=a^3+3ab^2+3a^2b+b^3$ which you already know its equal to $i\sqrt{3}+2$ So you just have to "guess" the values of $a,b$ s.t $a^3+3ab^2+3a^2b+b^3=i\sqrt{3}+2$.

That's right. thank you dude.

Ill edit the post to include that part too.

the "norm"  of $a + b \sqrt{-3}$   being $a^2 + 3 b^2,$   we check that $(-10)^2 + 3 \cdot 9^2 = 100 + 243 = 343 = 7^3.$  So we are looking for a cube root $x + y \sqrt{-3}$ with  $x^2 + 3 y^2 = 7$ and hoping to get integers
